# Excel macro - data manipulation

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am new to macros and I need help for the below.

[image]

I have the values as above. I want to count the total number of apples, oranges, and so on. 
I want the final result in another sheet as below
Apples = 15 Banana = 17 Mangoes = 15 Oranges = 13 Melon = 7

I understand that I need to first split them and store them in an array and loop to count them. But I am not sure how to do it. Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: If this is something your really need VBA for (it will need to be done multiple times or with a large amount of data), I'd examine the data source and have it kick it out in a usable format.  One column being Fruit and the next column being Qty.  That would make your life extreme simple and no need for VBA at all.

Comment: the above is just an example. The original file has large amount of data generated as a csv file. I would like to understand the logic on how to split the numbers and then count them.

Comment: If you want to avoid VBA you might consider putting all the cells in one column and then using `Text to Columns` under the `Data` tab on the ribbon. Then you can just use some `COUNTIF()` formulas. That would be the easiest route.

Comment: I added comments to my solution that uses arrays extensively and covers non-standard list items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Function ConcatResults(rng As Range) As String
Dim rng1 As Range, tmpArray() As String, nameArray() As String, sumArray() As Double, counter As Long
For Each rng1 In rng 'for each cell in your range
    If InStr(rng1.Value2, "=") > 0 Then 'if it contains an equal sign
        tmpArray = Split(rng1.Value2, "=") 'the cell value gets split by the equal sign
        If NameIndex(tmpArray(0), nameArray) > -1 Then 'if the fruit name is found already in the name array
           sumArray(NameIndex(tmpArray(0), nameArray)) = sumArray(NameIndex(tmpArray(0), nameArray)) + CDbl(tmpArray(1)) 'then it adds the number to the existing name's corresponding sum
        Else 'otherwise
            ReDim Preserve nameArray(counter) 'it expands the array of fruit names
            ReDim Preserve sumArray(counter) 'and the corresponding sum array
            nameArray(counter) = tmpArray(0) 'adds the name to the last (open) place in the name array
            sumArray(counter) = CDbl(tmpArray(1)) 'adds the name to the last (open) place in the sum array
            counter = counter + 1 'increments the index for further potential list items
        End If
    End If
Next rng1
'exports data
For i = LBound(nameArray) To UBound(nameArray) 'for the whole set
    ConcatResults = ConcatResults & nameArray(i) & " = " & sumArray(i) & " " 'it concatenates [NAME] = [SUM]
Next i

ConcatResults = Left(ConcatResults, Len(ConcatResults) - 1) 'removes the ending space

End Function
Function NameIndex(str As String, arr() As String) As Long 'this function tells the index of the given string (fruit) in the [name]array
'defaults to -1
NameIndex = -1
On Error GoTo err 'if the array is not yet defined it outputs the default -1
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) 'for each item in the set
    If arr(i) = str Then NameIndex = i 'if it's the same as the item we're looking for then outputs its index
Next i
err:
End Function
```

The output is `Apples = 15 Oranges = 13 Mangoes = 15 Banana = 12 Bananas = 5 Melon = 7`, note *Bananas = 5* comes from a typo in the description.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, but could you tell me how to call the function in sub() ?

Comment: `Sub e()` / `MsgBox ConcatResults(Range("A2:G8"))` / `End Sub`. Do bear in mind that we are not a coding service; you should have a basic understanding of the environment and what you would like to achieve at this point. If my answer is the solution you were seeking, please mark it as such. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED WITH FIX TO SUBSCRIPT OUT OF RANGE AND TO PICK UP ANOMALIES +/- 's'**

Providing you only have 5 items as in your example, otherwise I would create arrays for the items to store the totals, looping through the array each time to see whether the next item already exists in the array to add the total up and adding it to the array if not.

```
Sub test()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim n, Apples, Oranges, Banana, Mangoes, Melon As Integer

Apples = 0
Oranges = 0
Banana = 0
Mangoes = 0
Melon = 0

n = 0
For Each Cell In Sheets(1).UsedRange.Cells
    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then GoTo 0

    arr = Split(Cell, "=")

    If Left(arr(0), 5) = "Apple" Then
    Apples = Apples + arr(1)
    End If

    If Left(arr(0), 6) = "Orange" Then
    Oranges = Oranges + arr(1)
    End If

    If Left(arr(0), 6) = "Banana" Then
    Banana = Banana + arr(1)
    End If

    If Left(arr(0), 5) = "Mango" Then
    Mangoes = Mangoes + arr(1)
    End If

    If Left(arr(0), 5) = "Melon" Then
    Melon = Melon + arr(1)
    End If

0
Next

Sheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = Apples
Sheets(2).Cells(2, 2).Value = Oranges
Sheets(2).Cells(3, 2).Value = Banana
Sheets(2).Cells(4, 2).Value = Mangoes
Sheets(2).Cells(5, 2).Value = Melon

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but the original file has more than 5 values. I just posted this as a sample. If you can provide one without the specific values, it would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer below mine may be more relevant then, just change the concatenate section to storing the data in cell references on another sheet.